# Error when running rnn.py on a config file

Tags: python, returnn

When I am trying to execute the following command:

```
python3.6 rnn.py demos/demo-act-lstm.12ax.config
```

([this config](https://github.com/rwth-i6/returnn/blob/master/demos/demo-act-lstm.12ax.config)).

I get the following error:

```
Device cpu0 proc exception: 

When compiling the inner function of scan the following error has been encountered: The initial state (`outputs_info` in scan nomenclature) of variable IncSubtensor{Set;:int64:}.0 (argument number 2) has dtype float32, while the result of the inner function (`fn`) has dtype float64. This can happen if the inner function of scan results in an upcast or downcast.

Unhandled exception <class 'ValueError'> in thread <_MainThread(MainThread, started 140379522152192)>, proc 12162.
```

Comment: The error is because of `~/.theanorc`, as I wrote in my answer. However, in most cases the config file would also be relevant, and you should also post the config here (or link it). I'm also not really sure what you are trying to do here. What demo is that?

Comment: It is the same file as https://github.com/rwth-i6/returnn/blob/master/demos/demo-act-lstm.12ax.config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not follow the [installation documentation](http://returnn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) properly. You need to have this in your `~/.theanorc`:

```
[global]
device = cpu
floatX = float32
```